# Can't sign in to SkyDrive using javascript SDK

Tags: javascript, onedrive

I have a simple html page which starts the signin process after a button is clicked. Clicking the button opens a new window. I am able to enter my username/password successfully and I am also able to say "Yes" to the prompt asking if I want to "Let this app access your info". However, after that, the window remains blank.

The URL shows that the request was successful given that it contains an access token. But the window remains open and I am unable to see any other indication that my request succeeded. The error message that's printed to the log is:

```
[WL]WL.login: The popup is closed without receiving consent.
```

I get this error after I manually close the window. If I don't, nothing happens.

Here is what I have:

```
WL.Event.subscribe("auth.login", onLogin);
WL.Event.subscribe("auth.sessionChange", onSessionChange);

WL.init({
    client_id: "REPLACED_WITH_ID",
    redirect_uri: "https://login.live.com/oauth20_desktop.srf",
    scope: ["wl.signin","wl.skydrive"], 
    response_type: "token"
});

var session = WL.getSession();
if (session) {
    log("You are already signed in!");
} else {
    log("bout to login"); //
    scope: ["wl.skydrive"]
    WL.login({
    }).then(
        function (response) {
            log("after login: " + response);
        }, 
        function (responseFailed)
        {
            log(responseFailed);
            document.getElementById("response").innerText =
                "Error signing in: " + responseFailed.error_description
        }
    );
}
```

Is there a way to get the access token or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Have you tried experimenting with a different redirec_uri ?

Comment: Yes. You are required to use either this or your redirect URI which you specified on the Skydrive developer page.

Comment: I'm stacked on the same issue, have you passed over this?. Thanks